# How to create a report of multiple SKUs in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to combine a list of 10 SKUs into one view so that I can see how the sales of these products do from day to day and week to week.

I've tried to go to reports->conversion->ecommerce->product results and add all the SKUs into  the advanced filter, but I don't get any data if I add more than one SKU.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on your 10 specific product SKUs using the pipe | which is the regex OR operator.

Example:

```
ProductSKU1|ProductSKU2|ProductSKU3|ProductSKU4|ProductSKU5|ProductSKU6|ProductSKU7|ProductSKU8|ProductSKU9|ProductSKU10
```